# How to implement conditional endpoints with Servant?

Tags: haskell, servant

I have an existing server written using the Servant library. 
I now want to make the endpoints conditional such that based on certain configuration or logic, I would like to serve (or not serve) a particular endpoint.
What's the best way to do this?

I've tried using `EmptyAPI` from `Servant.API` but it didn't work. 
For context, I'm currently using `toServant` from `Servant.API.Generic` for most of my routes.

Comment: What would you like to happen if a client tries to access a particular endpoint, but your consideration says that this endpoint shouldn't be served?

Comment: What would normally happen if any client tries to access an endpoint that's not being served/does not exist. Either a 404 or some configured error message or page?

Comment: You can't conditionally use the proxy value because the type must match.  Instead you can `if b then serve api1 else serve api2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with returning 404 when the endpoint is "off", you can do that by throwing the corresponding Servant error:

```
server = toServant MyEndpointsRecord
    { ...

    , cleverEndpoint = do
        shouldServe <- isCleverEndpointEnabled
        if shouldServe 
            then serveCleverEndpoint
            else throwError err404

    ...
    }
```

You can also wrap this for reuse if you need to do this often:

```
guarded checkConfig f = do
    shouldServe <- checkConfig
    if shouldServe 
        then f
        else throwError err404


server = toServant MyEndpointsRecord
    { ...

    , cleverEndpoint = guarded isCleverEndpointEnabled serveCleverEndpoint

    ...
    }
```